# Java program only returns the input, does not show calculation result in methods

Tags: java, methods, parameters

For factorial calculation, euler number and  euler power x  calculation, I prepared below "factorial" class and "behzat" class. When I execute the program; it returns the same input number to me for each methods. Can anyone advise what the problem is.  Many thanks  for your kind assistance.

**This is the factorial class:**

```
public class factorial {

    public void instructions()
    {
        System.out.printf("Enter your choice:\n",
        " 1 to calculate a factorial value of an integer.\n",
        " 2 to calculate mathematical constant e.\n",
        " 3 to calculate e^x.\n",
        " 4 to end.\n");        
    }  // End of instructions


    // ******* a ********

    public double calculateInputValue (int n){
    int ans=1;
    for (int i = 1; i <= n; i++){
    ans = ans * i;
    }
    return ans;
    } // end method calculateInputValue


    // ******  b *******
    public double calculate_e_value(double terms)
    {
    double e = 1;

    for(int i = 1; i < terms; i++)
        e += ((double) 1 /(calculateInputValue(i) )); 

    return e;
    }


    //********* c  ***********      
    public double compute_ex(double terms)  // method for e power x
    {
    int x = 1;  
    double e = 1;

    for( int i = 1; i < terms; i++)
        e += (Math.pow(x,i)/(calculateInputValue(i) )); 
        x++; 
    return e;


    }

}
```

**and behzat class  including main:**

```
import java.util.Scanner;   // Program uses scanner. 

public class behzat
{ 


   private static Scanner input;

public static void main(String[] args)
   {


       factorial myfactorial = new factorial();
       myfactorial.instructions(); 
       System.out.printf(" ? "); 
       int choice; 
       input = new Scanner(System.in);
       choice = input.nextInt();

       switch(choice) 
       {  
       case 1 :             
          System.out.printf("enter number for factorial calculation");
          int number = 1; 
          number = input.nextInt();
          myfactorial.calculateInputValue(number);

          // If integer greater or 0, print "factorial is equal to: %d"
          if ( number >= 0 )                          
            System.out.printf("Factorial is equal to:%d\n", number);
          // otherwise, print "Input value not valid." 
          else
            System.out.printf( "Error: Input value not valid.\n");
          break;

        case 2:

            System.out.printf("enter number of terms to calculate of e constant.\n");
            number = input.nextInt();
            myfactorial.calculate_e_value(number);
            System.out.printf(" e value is %2d\n", number);
            break;


        case 3:

           System.out.printf("enter power x value of e constant.\n");
           number = input.nextInt();
           myfactorial.compute_ex(number);
           System.out.printf(" e power x is %2d\n", number);
           break;

        default: 
            myfactorial.instructions();
        }

   }

}
```

Comment: Not regarding your problem but still feel it should be said: it is common practise to let Classes start with Capital letters and functions/variables with small letters in Java.

Comment: Many thanks for your kind interest, Adrian.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

you should retrieve the returned value of each method in a variable and then print it . For example:

```
int val = myfactorial.calculateInputValue(number);
if ( val >= 0 )                          
System.out.printf("Factorial is equal to:%d\n", val);
```

Adapt this way everywhere you calling some method and print the retrieved value. That simply would solve your problem.

Answer (score 0):

At least in your factorial result print statement:

```
if ( number >= 0 )                          
        System.out.printf("Factorial is equal to:%d\n", number);
```

You are printing the input `number` not the result of factorial, which certainly always print your input `number`.

You have to store the factorial result:

```
long res = myfactorial.calculateInputValue(number);
if ( number >= 0 )                          
        System.out.printf("Factorial is equal to:%d\n", res);
```

assuming that your factorial does not result in overflow.
Similar error for the other two cases.

Answer (score 0):

I think you ought to have the input express the result of your function:

Example:

```
number = input.nextInt();
number = myfactorial.calculateInputValue(number);

// If integer greater or 0, print "factorial is equal to: %d"
if ( number >= 0 )                          
System.out.printf("Factorial is equal to:%d\n", number);
```